# How to allow any other role in Spring Security?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security

How you would do an expression to permit access to all roles unless one, without declaring them all in spring-security.xml?

We have four roles: `private`, `user1`, `user2` and `user3`. `private` is the only role that can execute certain services. The other are allowed only to `user1`, `user2` and `user3`.

```xml
<http pattern="/priv/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('private')"/>
    <http-basic/>
</http>

<http pattern="/pub/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="!hasRole('private')"/>
    <http-basic/>
</http>
```

I know that with this, the problem would be solved, but in the case of an user having `private` and `user2` for example, this user should can execute the `/priv/` and the `/pub/` operation. How could the xml be configured?
If the user has two roles (`private` and one more of the others), both operations would be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `RoleHierarchy` to simplify your security configuration.

```xml
<bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
    <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
</bean>
<bean id="roleHierarchy"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <property name="hierarchy">
        <value>
            ROLE_PRIVATE > ROLE_USER
            ROLE_USER > ROLE_USER1 > ROLE_USER2 > ROLE_USER3
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then in your `http` configuration:

```xml
<http pattern="/priv/**">
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('PRIVATE')"/>
            <http-basic/>
 </http>

<http pattern="/pub/**">
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
            <http-basic/>
 </http>
```

This way your `ROLE_USER` will "embed" all other `ROLE_USERX` rules, and `ROLE_PRIVATE` will embed all from `ROLE_USER`.

You should also refer to the [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authz-hierarchical-roles).

Comment: But the case is: I can have new different permissions, and all of them but private can execute the /pub/**. I am finding a way to add new permissions and acceding to /pub without modifing spring-secutiry.xml avoiding deployments every time a role is added

Comment: Why are you adding a new role with no different control access?

Comment: Because the only role that cannot access to /pub/ will be 'PRIVATE' only, the rest, actual and future roles will access. Also, an user with private and another role should access /pub/

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an extension of `WebSecurityExpressionRoot` with a method `boolean hasAnyRoleExcept(String... ignoredRoles)`

---

sketch *(written without IDE support)*:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;

public class MyWebSecurityExpressionRoot extends WebSecurityExpressionRoot {

   public MyWebSecurityExpressionRoot(final Authentication a, final FilterInvocation fi) {
      super(a, fi);
   }

   public boolean hasAnyRoleExcept(String... ignoredRoles) {
        //see SecurityExpressionRoot.hasAnyRole
        Set<String> roles = 
            AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(
               getAuthentication().getAuthorities());

        //find a not ignored role
        for (String role : roles) {
            if (!ignoredRoles.contains(role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
   }
}
```

To register it:

```
public class MyWebSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler {

    //Attention: override setTrustResolver too.
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    @Override
    protected SecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi) {
        MyWebSecurityExpressionRoot root = new MyWebSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, fi);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(trustResolver);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        return root;
    }
}
```

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" ...>
    ...

    <security:expression-handler ref="myWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRoleExcept('private')"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="myWebSecurityExpressionHandler" class="MyWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
```